# openSuse, new user cannot login

Tags: linux, opensuse, openssh

I am using openSuse 12.3.

I have created a new user using:

```
linux-amvn:~ # useradd -m -G users,dev -s /bin/bash -p pass123 harbir-PC
```

The user `harbir-PC` is not able to login, when I try to log using `ssh`.
I went ahead and looked into the `/etc/passwd` file and I see the following:

```
harbir:x:1000:100:harbir:/home/harbir:/bin/bash
kdm:x:489:487:KDM Display Manager daemon:/var/lib/kdm:/bin/false
harbir-PC:x:1001:100::/home/harbir-PC:/bin/bash
```

There is a difference between the user `harbir` and `harbir-PC`.

I have no problem with the user `harbir` (who I have created during installation), but I need to login using the user `harbir-PC`.

I also checked the `/etc/shadow`, and passwords are encrypted.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of `useradd`? It says `-p The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).`

Comment: From man page of `useradd` if you look for option `p`, it has the information as specified above and it has this information as well.  `The default is to disable the account.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually run `passwd` after `useradd` to set the password as I want it. But if you are provisioning and doing this from a script you may need to use `crypt` and provide the encrypted password on the command line.

Comment: yea, I ran passwd separately after creating the user, and now the user is being able to log in, just wondering why wouldn't it work earlier.

Comment: As mentioned, the argument to useradd's -p option needs to be an encrypted password, not a clear-text password. So you need to use crypt first to get the encrypted form of the clear-text password, and then use that. This is described on the useradd man page: "The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3)".